# Repeater inside Group ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, nested-loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress and trying to loop a repeater inside a group. All I get is "Notice: Array to string conversion in..."

What's wrong & how do I fix it?

```
<?php if( have_rows('start_horlurar') ): while ( have_rows('start_horlurar') ) : the_row();  ?>

<?php $horlur = get_sub_field('horlur'); ?>

<?php if( have_rows( $horlur['arsmodeller_lankar']) ): while ( have_rows($horlur['arsmodeller_lankar']) ) : the_row();  ?>

<?php echo get_sub_field('lank'); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: please post minimal code

Comment: I did, but it disappeared.

Comment: what is this field "lank"  text or image or someother

Comment: It's the sub field in the repeater "arsmodeller_lankar"

Comment: try this, the_field('lank');

Comment: doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't seem to loop the repeater at all

Comment: Here's a plain and simple guide to repeaters inside groups (https://wpza.net/use-a-repeater-inside-a-group/) if it helps anyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In nested ACF Repeaters, you need not to add the reference of parent repeater - just add the repeater name alone. Try like this.

```
<?php
if( have_rows('start_horlurar') ): while ( have_rows('start_horlurar') ) : the_row(); 
    echo get_sub_field('horlur');
    if( have_rows('arsmodeller_lankar') ): while ( have_rows('arsmodeller_lankar') ) : the_row(); 
        echo get_sub_field('lank');
    endwhile; endif;
endwhile; endif;
?>
```

**UPDATED CODE:**
You need to loop the ACF Group field too like ACF Repeater. Try like this.

```
<?php
if( have_rows('start_horlurar') ): while ( have_rows('start_horlurar') ) : the_row(); 
    if( have_rows('horlur') ): while ( have_rows('horlur') ) : the_row();       
        if( have_rows('arsmodeller_lankar') ): while ( have_rows('arsmodeller_lankar') ) : the_row(); 
            echo get_sub_field('lank');
        endwhile; endif;
    endwhile; endif;
endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Comment: It dosen't output anything. Not even echo "hello world";

Comment: Can you confirm that `start_horlurar` is parent repeater name & `arsmodeller_lankar` is the child repeater under that?

Comment: But the `lank` field seems to be under `start_horlurar` and not `arsmodeller_lankar`?

Comment: Seems `horlur` a group field between those, can you just confirm the hierarchy - `start_horlurar` (repeater) > `horlur` (group) > `arsmodeller_lankar` (repeater)?

Comment: Yes! :) Therefore the title of the question

Comment: No problem! :) It Worked, you're a genius!

Comment: The updated code it was worked for me (i.e. the group needed to be looped as well). Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I believe this was answered correctly, but it did not seem clear enough for those looking for a generic implementation.

```
<?php

if( have_rows('your_group') ): while ( have_rows('your_group') ) : the_row(); 

    if( have_rows('your_repeater') ): while ( have_rows('your_repeater') ) : the_row();       

        echo get_sub_field('repeater_sub_field');

    endwhile; endif;

endwhile; endif;

?>
```

Normally with groups you can reach specific subfields by using:

```
<?php 

$group_var = get_field['your_group']; 

$group_sub_field_var = $group_var['group_sub_field']

?>
```

However, it seems with repeaters nested inside of groups you cannot use this strategy and are forced to loop through a group first using `have_rows()` to even reach the repeater.

If you look at the [group documentation on ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/) it mentions how looping through a group is done like a repeater. Also the [`have_rows()` documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) has more detail about nested loops using `have_rows()`.

Answer (score 15):

I find the double loop messy and not needed. 
I realize this is old, but I just had this issue and didn't want to have two loops.

For my group ('group') and my repeater ('repeater'), with a subfield of ('subfield') this is what I did.

```
     $group = get_field('group');
     $repeaters = $group['repeaters'];
     foreach($repeaters as $repeater) {
         echo $repeater["subfield"];
       }
```

Super easy, and it's much more clean. You can add your 'if' statements if needed and not controlled my mandatory fields.

I find this method important for quick and dirty. I use groups for almost everything to be able to create a better user experience for the custom fields in the back end. Most of my custom fields are in groups and grabbing the args, I want it to be as little code and as clean as possible.

Let me know if you guys find any issues with this method, especially in regards to performance.

Comment: This worked  for me, and is neater than the double loop

Comment: ...but you're loosing the benefit of checking if group, or repeater, or sub field exists.

Answer (score 0):

I format it like this, I think it's much cleaner:

```
<?php if(have_rows('features_repeater')): while(have_rows('features_repeater')): the_row(); if(have_rows('features_group')): while(have_rows('features_group')): the_row(); ?>
    
    <h1><?php echo get_sub_field('title'); ?></h1>

<?php endwhile; endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```